# Валидация данных в коде приложения или в базе данных

Tags: mysql

Если в колонку с типом CHAR(50) вставить строку, длина которой превышает 50 символов, то MySQL вернёт ошибку

Вопрос: 
Нужно ли проводить валидацию длины вставляемых строк в серверном коде приложения, чтобы не нагружать MySQL дополнительной работой или же пусть этим занимается MySQL(как в примере выше)?

Comment: В идеале, надо проверять и на клиенте и на сервере. В самой базе, я не думаю, что нужна проверка - ни вижу причины.

Comment: Вам же известно в чем отличие типов `CHAR` и `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не совсем понимаю как это относится к моему вопросу

Comment: К вопросу не относится никак. Просто интересуюсь. А то Вы экономите на нагрузке MySQL, а сами храните по 50 символов на запись

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ситуация с CHAR(50) была придумана для этого вопроса. Можете что-нибудь конкретно по вопросу подсказать?

Comment: Поверь, MySQL-серверу проще отказать во вставке по ошибке, чем вставить данные в таблицу. Так что при отсутствии валидации данные, которые не могут быть вставлены, наоборот, разгружают сервер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем раньше ошибка обнаруживается, тем дешевле ее обработка

- Если клиент не сможет ввести более 50 символов, то он не отправит вам некорректные данные
- Если сервер обнаружит некорректное значение, то он сможет внятно объяснить клиенту, что не так
- Валидация на уровне базы нужна, чтобы невозможно было вставить некорректное значение

Общепринятой практикой считается наличие всех трех уровней проверок. Тем более, что проверку на уровне БД Вы отключить не сможете никак.